# Вырезка картинки

Tags: java, изображения

Допустим у меня есть некий имейдж с размерами 200, 50:

```
Image sprite;
//...
try{
    sprite = ImageIO.read(new File("Test.jpg"));
}catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace()}
```

Мне нужно взять из этого спрайта картинку, с координатами на спрайте 0, 0, 100, 20.
Я предполагаю что это как-то можно сделать через CropImageFilter, но как?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  private BufferedImage cropImage(BufferedImage src, Rectangle rect) {
      BufferedImage dest = src.getSubimage(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height);
      return dest; 
   }
```